# Best way to hide a toolbox associated with a UserControl in .NET 2.0?

Tags: winforms, .net-2.0

I've recently come across the following situation.  I have a `UserControl` that can show a modeless toolbox.  If the user has shown the toolbox, I'd like to hide and show it appropriately as the `UserControl` itself becomes invisible or visible, respectively.  The `UserControl` can be embedded in an arbitrary number of parent containers, such as a `GroupBox` or `TabPage`, which can influence whether or not the `UserControl` is actually visible despite its own `Visible` property being `True`.

In WPF, it seems like I could use the `IsVisibleChanged` event of the `UserControl` to handle this.  Is there an equivalent for WinForms?  What would a general solution in .NET 2.0 be?

EDIT: Here is the solution that I arrived at.  Is there a better solution?

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    private List<Control> _ancestors = new List<Control>();
    private bool _isVisible = false;

    public MyControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ParentChanged += OnParentChanged;
        VisibleChanged += OnVisibleChanged;
    }

    private void OnParentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control c in _ancestors)
        {
            c.ParentChanged -= OnParentChanged;
            c.VisibleChanged -= OnVisibleChanged;
        }

        _ancestors.Clear();

        for (Control ancestor = Parent; ancestor != null; ancestor = ancestor.Parent)
        {
            ancestor.ParentChanged += OnParentChanged;
            ancestor.VisibleChanged += OnVisibleChanged;

            _ancestors.Add(ancestor);
        }
    }

    private void OnVisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool isVisible = Visible;
        foreach (Control c in _ancestors)
        {
            if (!c.Visible)
            {
                isVisible = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (isVisible != _isVisible)
        {
            _isVisible = isVisible;

            // Control visibility has changed here
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, when working with multiple forms or controls, properties like `Visible` require that you set them manually. It's a pain, and somewhat tedious to go through all controls whose properties are dependent on other controls' properties.

What if you set the UserControl.Tag to reference your toolbox?

Comment: I'm accepting this because there seems to be no alternative to checking the visibility myself.  I did not use Tag.